# Custom LoginModule in Websphere 7

Tags: java, websphere, jaas

I wrote a custom LoginModule which works just fine in JBoss, however, now I need to deploy it on Websphere 7 and I just can't find the appropriate way to register the LoginModule. Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an application login module that has to be used by all applications on the server, put it into WSLogin JAAS configuration:

In admin console, the clickpath would be (WAS 6.1, but 7 will be simillar): 
Security > Global security > Authentication > JAAS configuration > Application logins > WSLogin

Comment: It is exactly the same for WAS 7 too.

Comment: where to keep the jar file of the login module if it is a system login?